# PHP/HTML newsletter issue

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a simple form on my WordPress site that allows users to sign-up to a newsletter:

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="newsletter.php">
<input type="text" class="form" name="Email" size="20" placeholder="Email address">
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" name="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

After submitting the email address, the user is being redirected to a new site called newsletter.php and the following message appears: *Your email address has been successfully submitted*

**PHP**

```
<?php
$recipient = "blabla@mail.com";
$subject = "Newsletter subscription";
$sender = $recipient;
$body .= "Add this email adress to the newsletter: \n";
$body .= " ".$_REQUEST['Email']." \n";
mail( $recipient, $subject, $body, "From: $sender" ) or die ("Mail could not be sent.");
echo "Your email address has been successfully submitted";
?>
```

What I'd like to know now: How can I display the 'success message' on the WordPress site instead of newsletter.php?

The perfect solution would be a small div that opens below the sign-up form.

Comment: I'd build a page template in your theme, and put newsletter.php in it. Assign the template to a page in Wordpress and you're good to go.

Comment: @RelevantUsername that's hardly the cleanest and easiest way to do it. You're bringing in an entirely new language into the problem.

Comment: Thanks guys, guess I forgot to mention that I neither know Ajax nor JavaScript :) Will try to find some code on the interwebs now...EDIT: Nicholas, this sounds like a good way. I will try it first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change the form to look like this:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="form" name="Email" size="20" placeholder="Email address">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" name="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

(No `action` attribute means "submit to the current URL".)

And then add your PHP to the same page the form is on, as well as adding a check so that it only runs after the form is submitted:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Email'])) {
        $recipient = "blabla@mail.com";
        $subject = "Newsletter subscription";
        $sender = $recipient;
        $body .= "Add this email adress to the newsletter: \n";
        $body .= " ".$_REQUEST['Email']." \n";
        mail( $recipient, $subject, $body, "From: $sender" ) or die ("Mail could not be sent.");
        echo "<div>Your email address has been successfully submitted</div>";
    }
?>
```

You probably also want to change your error handling strategy to output `<div class="error">` or somesuch instead of dying.

---

I haven't used Wordpress in a while, so I'm not sure of the specifics there, but if this were a barebones PHP site you could just have it all together in the first page's source:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="form" name="Email" size="20" placeholder="Email address">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" name="Submit"></p>
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Email'])) {
        $recipient = "blabla@mail.com";
        $subject = "Newsletter subscription";
        $sender = $recipient;
        $body .= "Add this email adress to the newsletter: \n";
        $body .= " ".$_REQUEST['Email']." \n";
        mail( $recipient, $subject, $body, "From: $sender" ) or die ("Mail could not be sent.");
        echo "<div>Your email address has been successfully submitted</div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of posting to Newsletter.php, you could make the page post to itself and process the subscription there. Or Newsletter.php could be headless and redirect you back to the referrer where you could then display the subscription message. But this is quite antiquated, and any Ajax post-back solution will certainly be more sexy.

Answer (score 0):

```
If $sender = $recipient;
```

Then how to know who has visited the site and subscribed to the page.
Rather the sender mail has to be the email address of the person who has subscribed to the newsletter.

Comment: Hello Ammar, you were answering a 7 year old question! Welcome to stackoverflow!